# Custom font used in entire app

Tags: android, fonts

So there are different ways to set your font in Android.
What i need to do is to set the font in combination with a `custom font` and thereby over the `entire app`.

Now after some research i have 2 options.

- Override `EditText` and set font, use this class in my layout xml.
- Add a font to my AppTheme in my styles.xml.

Now i prefer the last option, this is obviously in my position the best way to go since i use the same font in my entire app.
Now the problem is, in my `Assets/font/` folder i added the font i want to use but i can't use this in my styles.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:typeface"> Here? </item>
</style>
```

How to add my font as typeface. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    public class CustomTextView extends EditText {

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    if (!isInEditMode())
        init();

}

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    if (!isInEditMode())
        init();

}

public CustomTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    if (!isInEditMode())
        init();
}

public void init() {
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), Constants.FONTPATH);
    setTypeface(tf);

}

  }
```

Then Use in XMLwith ;

```
     <pkgname.CustomTextView android:id="@+id/txt" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />
```

Comment: That's not my question. This was my first option. And thereby you override the textview and not the edittext as i mention. But beside this, i know of this option and in my position its not the most efficient way. It's like a plan b.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way we can access external assets in xml files.

Comment: In the meantime i didn't find any way to solve this either. I just go with an custom Textview. Hope there will be something for this in the future. It makes the code much more cleaner.